# Getting Glimpse to work with EF6 and MVC5

Tags: glimpse

This question has been asked a few times, but never been answered, so hopefully we can get it answered now.

I have an existing project with numerous contract classes and EF6 data access projects all used from my MVC5 web project.

I want to use glimpse, so I installed glimpse on my MVC web project.

However after doing so, I keep getting the following error:

> Unable to determine the provider name for provider factory of type
>   'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientFactory'. Make sure that the ADO.NET
>   provider is installed or registered in the application config.

When I uninstall glimpse, it all works again. Now after doing some googling it will seem that this is an issue out there, but I cannot find anywhere that someone addresses it with a definitive answer, and every suggestion that I have tried, have not fixed it.

I had glimpse installed before when I was still using EF5, and it all worked without any issues, but I have not had any luck since moving to EF6.

Hopefully it is a small configuration I am missing.

Any help is appreciated.

*STACKTRACE*

```
       [NotSupportedException: Unable to determine the provider name for provider factory of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientFactory'. Make sure that the ADO.NET provider is installed or registered in the application config.]
   System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderFactoryExtensions.GetProviderInvariantName(DbProviderFactory factory) +290
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DefaultInvariantNameResolver.GetService(Type type, Object key) +248
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetService>b__0(Tuple`2 k) +75
   System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory) +72
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.CachingDependencyResolver.GetService(Type type, Object key) +210
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.<>c__DisplayClass3.<GetService>b__0(IDbDependencyResolver r) +60
   System.Linq.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext() +66
   System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate) +161
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ResolverChain.GetService(Type type, Object key) +250
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.RootDependencyResolver.GetService(Type type, Object key) +106
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.<>c__DisplayClass3.<GetService>b__0(IDbDependencyResolver r) +60
   System.Linq.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext() +66
   System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate) +94
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ResolverChain.GetService(Type type, Object key) +250
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.CompositeResolver`2.GetService(Type type, Object key) +102
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DbDependencyResolverExtensions.GetService(IDbDependencyResolver resolver, Object key) +145
   System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbConnectionExtensions.GetProviderInvariantName(DbConnection connection) +71
   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.get_ConnectionString() +343
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalConnection.GetStoreConnectionString(DbConnection connection) +54
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalConnection.OnConnectionInitialized() +71
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.EagerInternalConnection..ctor(DbConnection existingConnection, Boolean connectionOwned) +61
   System.Data.Entity.DbContext..ctor(DbConnection existingConnection, Boolean contextOwnsConnection) +94
   ......Forms.EFModel.FormsEntities..ctor(DbConnection connection) in d:\.....\.....Online\Main\Source\Web\......Forms.EFModel\_FormsEntities.cs:10
   ......Forms.EFModel.FormsWorkspace.<CreateUnitOfWork>b__0(DbConnection c) in d:\.....\.....Online\Main\Source\Web\......Forms.EFModel\FormsWorkspace.cs:19
   ......Common.EntityFramework.EntityUnitOfWork`1.get_Context() in d:\.....\.....Online\Main\Source\Web\......Common.EntityFramework\EntityUnitOfWork.cs:66
   ......Forms.Repositories.FormsBaseRepository.GetForms(IEnumerable`1 formNumbers, FormStatusGroup statusGroup, Nullable`1 formType, Permission permission) in d:\.....\.....Online\Main\Source\Web\......Forms\Repositories\_FormsBaseRepository_IForms.cs:87
   ......Mvc.Areas.Me.Controllers.HomeController.AdviserSummary(String id) in d:\.....\.....Online\Main\Source\Web\......Mvc\Areas\Me\Controllers\HomeController.cs:148
   ......Mvc.Areas.Me.Controllers.HomeController.Index() in d:\.....\.....Online\Main\Source\Web\......Mvc\Areas\Me\Controllers\HomeController.cs:59
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +101
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +434
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +60
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.ActionInvocation.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod() +76
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +73
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +136
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +102
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3c() +117
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass45.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3e() +323
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass45.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3e() +323
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass45.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3e() +323
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass45.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3e() +323
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass45.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3e() +323
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass45.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3e() +323
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass30.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__2f(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +136
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +102
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass28.<BeginInvokeAction>b__19() +72
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1b(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +185
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +38
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9690164
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Comment: Can you provide us with the stacktrace you get when this happens?

Comment: Can you confirm which glimpse dlls are actually currently in your bin/obj? Also is there anything out of the ordinary with your setup (custom providers, etc)? Are you able to reproduce this issue on a smaller project you could share?

Comment: @anthonyv I can confirm that the dll's are in my bin folder. I do not have any custom providers. I simply have data access projects that uses EF6 to access the databases for me, then I have contract/service classes that uses the data access projects for their CRUD functions, and my web/MVC project simply uses my contract/service classes. I would think this setup is fairly standard, to separate your domain from your data access. I will attempt to reproduce it in a smaller project to share.

Comment: @spaceman - Nope, could not get it working. Works if I create a brand new solution, but cannot get it working on my existing solution/s

Comment: Same problem but I'm using MVC4 (+EF6+MySQL). Like @Ryk, initially I used EF 5 and Glimpse worked perfectly! Then, I uninstalled Glimpse and updated the project to EF 6. Now, when I install the Glimpse packages MVC4+EF6, even if Glimpse is turned off, as soon as the code calls a DB function it raises an `InvalidOperationException: No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.Odbc'. Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config file.`. Moreover, Web.config warns that `providers` is not a valid item